# XML Parsing Error: unclosed CDATA section in SVG

Tags: xml, svg

I have a SVG image that renders fine in chrome, but not in Firefox. It throws a parse error:

XML Parsing Error: unclosed CDATA section

Line Number 1, Column 292:

To me it looks like the cdata section is closed fine. Any idea's?

```
data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg clip-rule="evenodd" height="48px" width="48px" fill-rule="evenodd" image-rendering="optimizeQuality" shape-rendering="geometricPrecision" text-rendering="geometricPrecision" viewBox="0 0 5000 5000" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><defs><style type="text/css"><![CDATA[ .str0 {stroke:#434242;stroke-width:100}    .fil2 {fill:#434242}    .fil0 {fill:url(#id0)}    .fil1 {fill:url(#id1)} ]]></style><linearGradient gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" id="id0" x1="2500" x2="2500" y1="900.02" y2="1950.02"><stop offset="0" stop-color="#FCFCFD"/><stop offset="1" stop-color="#fff"/></linearGradient><linearGradient gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" id="id1" x1="2499.86" x2="2499.86" y1="3835.02" y2="1715"><stop offset="0" stop-color="#84ff45"/><stop offset="1" stop-color="#84e45c"/></linearGradient></defs><g id="Layer_x0020_1"><path class="fil0 str0" d="M500 1950v-950c0-55 45-100 100-100h1400l400 300h2000c55 0 100 45 100 100v650h-4000z"/><path class="fil1 str0" d="M600 4100h3800c55 0 98-45 100-100l100-2450c2-55-45-100-100-100h-1500l-400 300h-2100c-55 0-102 45-100 100l100 2150c3 55 45 100 100 100z"/><path class="fil2" d="M800 1100h1100c55 0 100 45 100 100s-45 100-100 100h-1100c-55 0-100-45-100-100s45-100 100-100z"/></g></svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not the XML, but the way it is being used in a URI with the `data:` URI scheme. Characters that are special in URIs need to be %HH-encoded; the part of the URI after the '#' has been stripped out and treated as a fragment identifier, leaving the CDATA section in the path part of the URI unclosed. You need to encode the '#' sign as %23.